# How to scroll a modal box in Selenium Python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I click on a link to accept Terms and conditions, a modal box pops up.
I need to scroll the modal pop up down, enable the Accept button and then click Accept.

I'm not able to scroll the modal box.

I tried:

```
context.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ars)
```

Where ars is the last element in the popup. This shows the last element ars in the modal without scrolling down.

I also tried:

```
actions = ActionChains(context.driver)
actions.move_to_element(ars)
```

This has the same behaviour: shows the last element ars in the modal without scrolling down.

Any other methods to scroll down are highly appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First try to find the new iframe which contains the name of the modal box.
modal_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div.....')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", modal_box)
Make sure its scrolling for the entire height. Then try to find the visibility of the accept button

Comment: Thanks Karthik for your answer! That page has no frames to switch to. But I can find the Modal box element.  With that element, I tried some scrolling options but didn't work.

Comment: I tried 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", modal_box) driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollHeight", modal_box)

Can you suggest any other scrolling options.